# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/layout/MainLayout'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

When I try and build and deploy my React 18.2.0 project to AWS Amplify, the build fails with what appears to be a module resolution error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/layout/MainLayout' in '/codebuild/output/src99999999/src/myapp/src/routes'`

The main layout file src/layout/MainLayout/index.tsx is:

```
export default MainLayout = () => { 
//code goes here
}
```

The file in src/routes/index.tsx imports the layout:

```
import MainLayout from 'src/layout/MainLayout';
```

The tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    // custom config
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "types": ["node", "webpack-env"],
    "typeRoots": ["./types"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

What could be causing this kind of build failure?

Comment: Try using a relative path in your import like `../../layout/MainLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. In *src/routes/index.tsx*, try deleting `src/` from the import statement: `import MainLayout from 'src/layout/MainLayout';` to `import MainLayout from 'layout/MainLayout';`
2. In *tsconfig.json*, change `baseUrl: "."` to `baseUrl: "src"`